# Wildfly stops abruptly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have used the wildlfy migration tool to migrate my apps from Wildfly 17 to 22. The migration is successful. However, Wildfly application server doesn't start. Here's the content of the server.log file:

```
2021-04-10 14:17:50,552 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
2021-04-10 14:17:50,593 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.4.2.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.7) 
2021-04-10 14:17:50,645 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at org.wildfly.extension.metrics@22.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.metrics.WildFlyMetricMetadata.<init>(WildFlyMetricMetadata.java:55)
    at org.wildfly.extension.metrics@22.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.metrics.MetricCollector.collectResourceMetrics0(MetricCollector.java:126)
    at org.wildfly.extension.metrics@22.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.metrics.MetricCollector.collectResourceMetrics0(MetricCollector.java:137)
    at org.wildfly.extension.metrics@22.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.metrics.MetricCollector.collectResourceMetrics0(MetricCollector.java:137)
    at org.wildfly.extension.metrics@22.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.metrics.MetricCollector.collectResourceMetrics(MetricCollector.java:69)
    at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye@22.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1005)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:744)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
    at org.jboss.as.server@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:451)
    at org.jboss.as.server@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:404)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

How to fix the error shown in the above log. My applications and configuration work like a charm with WF 17 Final.

Comment: That looks like it might be an issue in the configuration. Do you use the MicroProfile metrics?

Comment: No. How to disable it? The migration tool copied the config files of wildly 17 to wildly 22. On my server, WF 17 starts without throwing errors or displaying warnings.

Comment: Do you have a lot of configuration? Maybe it would be better to configure a plain wildfly 22 (btw. 23 is already out) instead of using the migration tool

Comment: No. I've deployed 6 wars. The applications require datasource access. I've also configured file handlers for some apps. The configuration isn't very complex.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the `prefix` is missing. You can fix this with CLI by adding a prefix. Using the embedded server the following should work.

```
embed-server
/subsystem=microprofile-metrics-smallrye:write-attribute(name=prefix, value=${wildfly.metrics.prefix:wildfly})
stop-embeddes-server
```

Since you're not using the subsystem you could just remove the subsystem. With JBoss CLI you'd do something like the following.

```
embed-server
/subsystem=microprofile-metrics-smallrye:remove
stop-embedded-server
exit
```

This assumes you're using the default `standalone.xml` file name. If you're configure file name is different you can use `embed-server --server-config=custom-standalone.xml`.

If you want to add the subsystem back you can use the following CLI command:

```
/subsystem=microprofile-metrics-smallrye:add(exposed-subsystems=["*"], prefix="${wildfly.metrics.prefix:wildfly}", security-enabled=false)
```

Comment: But why does it even fails when starting?

Comment: Without seeing the configuration I wouldn't able to say why it stops starting.

Comment: I'll update the answer as there is another fix as well, but this is a bug I was able to reproduce https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14697.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins has provided the correct work around. We have also fixed the error in the WildFly source code, which should ship in WildFly 24.